# Quotient of algebraic group by subgroup with trivial character group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and $H$ be a closed subgroup. Suppose that all homomorphisms of algebraic groups $H\to\mathbb{G}_m$ are trivial. How to prove that $G/H$ is quasi-affine?

Comment: I guess this sort of depends on how you are thinking about the quotient. Are you using Chevalley's construction (as the stabilizer in some vector space)? Or are you thinking more abstractly?

Comment: Yes, I am using Chevalley's construction. Actually it is an exercise 5.5.9(2) from the Springer's book.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using the setup of Springer.

Let $V$ be a $G$-representation and $W\subset V$ be  a line such that $H=\{g\in G\mid gW\subseteq W\}$ and $\mathfrak{h}=\{X\in\mathfrak{g}\mid XW\subseteq W\}$. Then $H$ acts (morphically) on $W$, inducing a morphism $H\to\mathbb{G}_m$, which is trivial by hypothesis. Therefore $H$ fixes every $w\in W$. In fact, as $W$ is one-dimensional, fixing one point is equivalent to fixing all points, so $H=\{g\in G\mid gw=w~\forall w\in W\}$. Fix $w\in W$. By essentially Chavalley's theorem, $Gx$ is open in its closure, hence quasi-affine. Let $o_w$ be the orbit map. Then (the first map is the obvious closed immersion)
$$
H\to G\overset{o_w}{\to}X,
$$
is constant, so has derivative zero. Thus

$$
\mathfrak{h}\subseteq\{X\in\mathfrak{g}\mid Xw=0~\forall w\in W\}\subseteq\{X\in \mathfrak{g}\mid XW\subset W\}=\mathfrak{h},
$$
whence equality. Therefore $\mathfrak{h}=\ker(do_w)$, so
$$
0\to\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}\to T_wX\to0
$$
is exact. (If you are in characteristic zero, this is superfluous.)

Therefore the orbit map is a bijection on both the group (obviously) and Lie algebra levels. It is then an isomorphism by theorem 5.3.2 in Springer.